# Spring Integration Java DSL How to use Spel for Service Activator

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, dsl

Could I know how to call Spel for .handle() (invoke Service Activator) in Spring Integration Java DSL?

The reason is I would like to call service activator with parameter. For XML, I could use Spel similar to "@myService.myMethod('param1', 'param2')" in expression attribute.

I can't find something similar in SI Java DSL

Answer (score 1):

There is no `.handle(String expression)` variant. We found it a bit redundant and decided that a Lambda variant with full Java access would be better:

```
.handle(payload, headers) -> this.myService.myMethod('param1', 'param2'))
```

where `this.myService` is an `@Autowired` for your service. All the parameter can be determined similar way.

Let us know why you insist for expression variant, when there is a full Java code access.

Comment: In my original XML config version, I have some expression be constructed on the fly based on the message in preceding components within the <chain />. That's why I am asking whether expression is supported during SI Java DSL migration.

Comment: OK. Why can't you achieve the same with just Java code using that Lambda sample? You still have full access to ApplicationContext and so on.

Comment: No problem. I will try to follow the Lambda sample for that.